# Find the locus of the point..

Tags: circles

Find the locus of a point from which the lengths of the tangents to the circles $x^2+y^2+4x+3=0$ and $x^2+y^2-6x+5=0$ are in the ratio $2:3$.

My Attempt:

Given circles are:
$$x^2+y^2+4x+3=0$$ and,
$$x^2+y^2-6x+5=0$$.
Let, $P(x_1,y_1)$ be a point on the locus, and $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the lengths of tangents.

According to question:
$T_1:T_2=2:3$
$\frac {T_1}{T_2}=\frac {2}{3}$
$3T_1=2T_2$.

Please help me to continue from here.

Comment: You have not tried anything. You have just restated what is given.. Do you know the equation of a tangent from an outside point? Show us what you have done.!

Comment: @Qwerty, I have shown, what I have done. I do not know, how to find the length of the tangents, or the equation of a tangent from an external point.

Comment: Study coordinate geometry first, especially the chapter on Circles. Then try to solve..

Comment: Hint:- $T_1 = \sqrt (x_1^2 + y_1^2 + 4x_1 + 3)$